# php session variables being echoed in title but not in og meta. Timing issue?

Tags: php, session-variables

UPDATE: All the data I am trying to write out below I actually SEE in the source code after page load.  When i say that it doesn't work, I am referring to the fact that the Facebook sharer is not picking up the og tags properly.

So I have a page that has numerous includes on the top doing some querying using session variables. Everything works great. The session vars all populate where I need them to when I echo them. Example:

```
<title><? echo $_SESSION["clientName"] ?></title>
```

The issue is when I start to write them to the og meta data.

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<? echo $_SESSION["clientName"]; ?>"/>
```

This gets me the data writing to the tag. I see it in source but Facebook sees it as nothing when the sharer is activated. 
Now if I define a local php variable that comes from no query using a session of any sort, it reads just fine with the sharer.

```
$clientName="University of Alaska";    
<meta property="og:description" content="<? echo $clientName; ?>"/>
```

It is very confusing to me! Is it not being set in time as that tries to fill first? One of my include pages is doing some heavy lifting. Does the session not totally set until everything is loaded?

FULL CODE

```
<?
session_start(); 
include '../includes/connection.php';
include '../includes/getMajorExtra.php';
include '../includes/getHiddenList.php';
include '../includes/getMajorList.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-type" content="IE=edge,chrome=1; charset=iso-8859-1">
<? 
$query = "SELECT clientID,active,customer FROM client WHERE     subdomain='".$_SESSION["clientURL"]."'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 $activeClient=$row["active"];
 $clientName=$row["customer"];
 $clientID=$row["clientID"];
}
mysql_free_result($result);
echo "<meta property=\"og:title\" content=\"".$clientName."\">";  
?>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://themajorkey.com/images/MK_logo.png"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="<? echo $_SESSION["clientName"]; ?>"/>
<title><? echo $_SESSION["clientName"]; ?></title>
```

Comment: is the `session_start();` before all sessions? Does your PHP error log show any warnings or messages? I doubt this is related to meta and is an issue else where (session has no value etc). Do you get a value if you echo the session on the line before the meta where it doesn't work?

Comment: Yeah the session is started. I literally write it out in two lines right next to each other. I echo the title no problem but it comes up blank in the og:description or og:title, etc.. No errors.

Comment: try changing the double quotes in your session variable to singles

Comment: I should note that I SEE the data in the og meta when I view the source but when something like Facebook tries to access the data it acts like it is not there. It is like it is being crawled before everything is done loading.

Comment: wait, the data is in the source code? You said "this gets you nothing", and that is not true. You said Facebook cannot access the data? This is something else entirely. You need to update your question to confirm the session data is fine and presented as should be by PHP (ie in the meta in source) and explain what the actual issue is more clearly.

Comment: Show us the full script with session_start(); included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you setting your $_SESSION["clientName"]? Facebook scrapes your link and cache meta data of your link. I guess facebook is not able to set your session data $_SESSION['clientName']. Are you setting that session data according to user login or something that user action have chosen? If that is case facebook will not be able to set that for you.

you can try this while generating sharing link:

your clientName sharing link can be this

```
http://yoursite.com/?clientName=<?php echo $_SESSION['clientName'];?>
```

and in your site you can do:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $_GET["clientName"]; ?>"/>
```

Add validations on $_GET["clientName"] as required.

Comment: I have them set from a log in page and they are carried over to here. But why does Facebook see the data if I echo something that is locally created and not a session?

Comment: So when you share on facebook, it wont be able to access your session data. as facebook will be scraping data form their server not clients browser. May be you can try passing get parameter in url while sharing which sets the clientName in og meta data.

Comment: $clientName="University of Alaska";    
<meta property="og:description" content="<? echo $clientName; ?>"/>, why is this found by Facebook?

Comment: I could go that route but the site URL has to end at the base of a folder. A redirect is occurring that is dropping them into a folder, which is really just a template. It then populates. So the domain always needs to be http:domain/1 or http:/domain/2 etc..  +1 for the thought of adding the queryString, and it does work, but it can't fit for the project.

Comment: Main thing here is that facebook won't be able to access your clients session data as it is scraping data from their server. $clientName="University of Alaska"; <meta property="og:description" content="<? echo $clientName; ?>"/> facebook can access this because here you are setting variable not session. Do you understand session and how it is set and accessed?

Comment: I think I need to read up as I thought they were comparable when I comes to this type of stuff. Thank you much for the help askkirati. Well done.